# If I use a DataContractResolver, does this restrict me to .NET only clients?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have attempted to use the SharedTypeResolver, also the less generic DataContractResolver's from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx).

The post mentions how the SharedTypeResolver requires .NET, and for tightly coupled scenarios, such as have the assembly shared by the service, and the client.

However, my question is this: Doesn't using a DataContractResolver AT ALL, require .NET and shared assemblies? How would the client use the Resolver, if it didn't have access to the same assemblies?

Currently all I have is .NET clients, but I don't want to alienate any potential customer who might be writing clients in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would make harder, but not impossible, for your java clients to generate proxies as your wsdl wouldn't contain the types you will send over the wire. There are tools that can be used to generate proxies automatically. Obviously they wouldn't be sufficient for generating the data model that is not described in wsdl. Those data models would have to be created manually. Therefore it is possible however it's probably too much effort and it'll be never done. For those reasons I'd advice you to avoid it.

Comment: So you are saying, that No it doesn't mean .NET only clients, but it would be much easier if that is the case. But, doesn't the fact that the resolver has to know about the types mean that the resolver has to be in .NET?

Comment: So, the java client could of course still use the types that are used in the contract, or wsdl. But, it wouldn't benefit from the additional types that the resolver is attempting to handle. I think I understand.

Comment: I believe they could handle even the additional types but the types would have to be implemented manually (not generated when creating the proxy). Also, they would have to have a similar deserialisation mechanism to the .NET resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Except for perhaps named pipes, ANY client running in ANY platform can talk with WCF. Whether or not it will be an enjoyably experience is the issue.

For cross platform communication I have had success with WCF binding WebHttpBinding (REST):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

But if your going to go that route then your missing out on so much that WCF has to offer, transactions, security, etc and might as well use the ASP.Net Web API.